# Teamcity failing to install packages via nuget

Tags: c#, log4net, teamcity, nuget

SOLVED - PLEASE SEE COMMENT

I have a project on team city that is failing to install the required packages.

This has has worked for over a year but this week all builds started failing.
my development process is as follows:

We use github and develop locally using visual studio. We have a windows teamcity agent that does our compiling, and a teamcity server that automatically runs builds.

I get this Error on a build:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(902, 9): error MSB3073: The command "nuget install C:\BuildAgent\work\MyProject\MyLibaries\Gelf4Net\Gelf4net\packages.config -o C:\BuildAgent\work\MyProject\MyLibaries\Gelf4Net\Gelf4net\Packages" exited with code 1.
```

In my packages.config i have the following packages i need to install:

```
package id="log4net" version="1.2.11"

package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.10"

package id="RabbitMQ.Client" version="2.8.7"
```

I have read through many topics on the net and have tried the following:

- removed all package folder from teamcity nuget (force new packages to be downloaded)
- updated nuget to latest version (2.5)
- re added all the references to the project and pushed
- re added the project to teamcity
- enabled and disabled nuget on teamcity
- added the new nuget 2.5 to teamcity

If I run "nuget install `C:\BuildAgent\work\MyProject\MyLibaries\Gelf4Net\Gelf4net\packages.config -o C:\BuildAgent\work\MyProject\MyLibaries\Gelf4Net\Gelf4net\Packages" on the build agent it works and installs the packages.`

The projects build and run locally.

Please any suggestions or help is appreciated

Comment: I have found the issue, our projects incude many other projects and unless the packages in each project are on the same version, teamcity will fail to build.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific setup of the user, and he answered himself in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue, our projects incude many other projects and unless the packages in each project are on the same version, teamcity will fail to build